# Does density of states at Fermi level reduce or increase for decreasing the diameter of a nanowire?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, plasma-physics

As we decrease the diameter of a nano wire /quantum wire, does the density of the states at Fermi level increase or decrease?. If it does then, Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be regarding a physical wire.
Yet the answer is more depends on the model you choose, which itself must change to accommodate for different wires.

The answer to your question depends first on the dispersion relation you assume which is tightly connected the distribution of electrons. For instance adding an impurity to your model will result in a different DOS.

That being said, and assuming we consider the electrons in the wire as free electrons (except for the confining potential), we can consider a quadratic dispersion as shown here:
https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter2/ch2_4.htm

In this case, changing the diameter might change your decision (this is a decision as it regards only to your model) to regard the wire as one or two dimensional. As shown in the link, this in turn alters the DOS.

Intuitively, as you increase the diameter, you make it easier for electrons to occupy modes transverse to the z axis of the wire. If these can indeed be occupied, you allow more more degrees of freedom, and more states with the same energy level. This is true as now you can have two quantum numbers namely; $n_x$ and $n_y$ or however you want to denote them. Thus you have more states with the same energies, equals larger DOS.